How to aggregate entries related to another Prisma model
I'm seeking guidance on how to aggregate (sum) a field across related models in my schema:
model PayrollBatch {
  id           Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  payrolls     Payroll[]
}

model Payroll {
  id             Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  employee       Employee      @relation(fields: [employeeId], references: [id])
  employeeId     Int
  payrollBatch   PayrollBatch  @relation(fields: [payrollBatchId], references: [id])
  payrollBatchId Int
  incomeEntries  IncomeEntry[]
}

model IncomeEntry {
  id           Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  payroll      Payroll    @relation(fields: [payrollId], references: [id])
  payrollId    Int
  amount       Float
}

Currently, I iterate through payrolls to sum the amount field in IncomeEntry for a specific PayrollBatch. Here's my approach:

const payrollBatch = await prisma.payrollBatch.findUnique({
  where: { id: batchId },
  include: {
    payrolls: {
      include: {
        incomeEntries: true,
      },
    },
  },
});

const totalAmount = payrollBatch.payrolls.reduce((acc, payroll) => {
  return acc + payroll.incomeEntries.reduce((acc, entry) => acc + entry.amount, 0);
}, 0);


Is there a more efficient way to achieve this using Prisma's query capabilities? Can I utilize aggregation directly on IncomeEntry.amount, or query all IncomeEntry records related to a specific PayrollBatch?
References:

Prisma Documentation on Aggregation

